# Передача данных сессии во view

Tags: node.js, express

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании логина с помощью passport и создания express сессии у меня выходит вот такая сессия:

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  flash: {},
  passport: { user: '5e5fd30277b47f2c6838e070' }
}
```

и чтоб вывести данные сессии во view, мне нужно сделать middleware который будет брать user id из сессии и забирать модель юзера из монго а потом можно отдавать данные модели в шаблон? Только как его передать таким образом чтоб я мог юзать его во всех представлениях?